# Struts 2 + Spring put a managed spring bean in session

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, struts2

Consider an Struts 2 + Spring 4 project.

For each login the `User` object is put in session. As a very simple action it will look

```
public class LoginProcess implements ServletRequestAware {

  @Inject
  private AuthenticationServices authenticationServices;

  public String execute() {
    //The login method makes a new User and fills its setters
    User newUser = authenticationServices.login(....);
    getServletRequest().getSession().setAttribute("USER_SESSION", user);
  }
}
```

As we manually make a new `User` object so it is not managed spring bean, and we can't use spring features in `User` class: `@Inject` , `@Value` ,...

I tried to change user as:

```
@Named
@Scope(value="session")
public class User { ...
    @Inject
    private AccountServices accountServices;

}
```

and inject the `User` in instead of calling `new User`, but I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:91)
```

Well although it describes the error, but I can not find how can I fix it, and I am not sure if this is the correct way at all. It seems that I can only use spring `session scope` been when I am using `spring mvc`

Any comments ?!

---

**Why I need this ?! (Simplified situation)**

The user object has a `getAccounts()` methods which get all user accounts. Getting user accounts is an expensive operation, and it is possible that a user does not require its accounts during its login.

So, instead of get user accounts as soon as user logs in, we let the get method get user accounts if it does not have it:

```
public class User() {
  private Accounts accounts;

  @Inject
  private AccountServices accountServices;

  Accounts getAccounts() {
    if (accounts == null) {
      accounts = accountServices.getUserAccountsFromDB(...)
    }
    return accounts;
  }
```

Comment: Any good reason to have something like `AccountServices` in `User`? Change your `User` object to simple pojo.

Comment: Any good reason to keep using Spring instead of using CDI ?

Comment: @AleksandrM I have update my question to address the issue !

Comment: @AndreaLigios we are using spring not only for its DI injection (which can be replace by CDI)  but for other spring features and projects which helped us a lot.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi IKR, I've used Spring a lot and loved it, then I discovered Java EE 6+ with JPA2, CDI, EJB3.x. I'm not going back for all the tea in China.

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: Do you have any further questions regarding this issue?

Comment: @AleksandrM It's crystal clear ;) thanks!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi: You're welcome.

Comment: I have asked a question about this design at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852033/design-a-java-pojo-with-lazy-loading-property. Please comment there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a new instance of `User` by yourself, instead get a bean from Spring context.

For example you can achieve it by implementing `ApplicationContextAware` interface and calling one of `getBean` methods.

```
User user = applicationContext.getBean(User.class);
// populate user and put it into session
```

In that way it is a Spring managed bean an all required properties should be injected.

BUT consider changing your `User` to a simple POJO and moving all business logic (such as fetching users accounts) to some more appropriate place, in that way your model layer will be cleaner and easily testable.

Comment: Just a tip: to access the `ApplicaitonContext` I used `@Inject
    private ApplicationContext appContext;` and then `appContext.getBean(User.class)`;