# Design a Java POJO with lazy loading property

Tags: java, session, design-patterns

Please consider below example:

A web application creates a user object for every logged in user. This object has simple `String` properties for `firstName`, `lastName` ...

Each user can have a `car` too. Consider that fetching the user `car` is very expensive, so we prefer not to set the users car when user logs in. Instead we want to get car when a use case needs it.

To implement this we have created a User pojo as:

```
public class User() {
  private String FirstName;
  private String LastName;   
  private Car car;
  //Here we have the service object, this could be injected with spring or JEE
  private CarServices carServices;

  public Car getCar() {
    //If the car is not fetched yet, go on and get it from your service
    if (car == null) {
      car = carServices.getCarFromDB(...)
    }
    return car;
  }

}
```

To initial user after a login:

```
User newUser = new User();
newUser.setFirstName("foo");
newUser.setLastName("bar");
//We just let user have service, so he can use this service latter
newUser.setCarServices( new CarServices() );
```

And every use case which needs the user car can get it easily:

```
newUser.getCar()
```

However, I have been argued that in this way my User object is not a simple pojo any more and this is not a good approach.

How can I achieve this requirement in better way.

Comment: You have declared `Car` as `cars` but later used `car` as the variable is it a typo? if so please correct it.

Comment: If the User class must encapsulate the way a Car is obtained, the code you have is the way to go. If obtaining the Car is something a User should rather not know about then use the classic setCar/getCar paradigm. Then, the contract is to make User clients set the Car before they get the Car, and Clients must handle a null getCar response. -- Also, a POJO User and a subclass UserWithCar might be an approach - depends on your overall design whether you'd prefer doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have been argued that in this way my User object is not a simple pojo

To anwer your question I would first like to go back a bit in history.

Pojo is a *plain old java object* and means that you only use "standard" java. The term was created at a time when J2EE had it's hype. At this time developers coded business logic in enterprise beans and this EJBs needed a lot of infrastructure code. This fact coupled buisness logic to an implementation technology. So Rebecca Parsons, Josh MacKenzie and Martin Fowler came to the conclusion that business logic would be more reuseable and easier to test if you just use standard java. Thus they created the term [pojo](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/09/26/the-difference-between-pojos-and-java-beans/), because developers like fancy names.

Your **`User`** class just depends on standard java and therefore **it is a pojo**.

Some developers argue that a pojo should not contain any logic. These developer prefer anemic models. Others say that a rich model is the better approach. I belong to the developers who prefer a rich model over an anemic model.

If you want to remove the `CarServices` dependency from the `User` class you can implement a **`Car` lazy loading proxy** just like hibernate or a jpa implementation does.

At least here are some of my thoughts to beans, pojos, anemic and rich domain models.

- [The difference between pojos and java beans](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/09/26/the-difference-between-pojos-and-java-beans/)
- [Anemic vs. Rich Domain Models](https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2011/10/01/anemic-vs-rich-domain-models/)

Hopefully it helps you when you discuss wih other developers.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a reference to a car, you could use a reference to a car supplier object whose implementation could cache the first result obtained (see Guava's `Supplier` and `MemoizingSupplier` classes). By doing so, you hide from the `User` object the fact that its car might or might not be present at instantiation time, and therefore make its implementation simpler (no more logic in the getter method).

Another advantage of this solution would be to break the coupling between the `User` and the `CarServices` classes (no need for the `carServices` property anymore). One could inject a supplier whose implementation would return a reference to an already available `Car` object, while another could pass an implementation that forwards the call to a `CarServices` service.

It wouldn't make the `User` class more of a POJO though (as explained in the first answer above), but people who have argued with your solution might like this one better because of it being simpler and less tightly coupled.