# Should objects that are put in the session and have dynamic getters be threadsafe

Tags: java, session, servlets, synchronization

Consider a `User` object which is set in the session.

One of object properties are set dynamically, as below:

```
public class User() {
  private String FirstName;
  private String LastName;   
  private Car car;
  //Here we have the service object, this could be injected with spring or JEE
  private CarServices carServices;

  public Car getCar() {
    //If the car is not fetched yet, go on and get it from your service
    if (car == null) {
      car = carServices.getCarFromDB(...)
    }
    return car;
  }

}
```

Should the `getCar()` be synchronized ?!

If you want to read more about this design please see [Design a Java POJO with lazy loading property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852033/design-a-java-pojo-with-lazy-loading-property)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes. The `User` object in the session could potentially be accessed by multiple threads, if the same user (who owns the session) makes multiple simultaneous requests.

If you don't care potentially loading the car multiple times, you could make `car` volatile:

```java
private volatile Car car;
```

Or, you could of course synchronize the whole method. Parallel access in this context is not very likely, so it should not have a significant performance impact either way.